# Window forms red x, but I can't find error notification

Tags: c#, winforms, opentk

I am using the OpenTK GLControl (a .Net OpenGL winforms control) to paint some things using opengl. The problem I am now facing is I am getting a big red cross or x on the windows form where the control lies, and its completely impossible to debug because I'm finding no way to know where the error is occurring.

I see no error notifications / exceptions. I had these same problems earlier with XNA, though I quit using it for other reasons.

Perhaps I'm missing something. Is there a window somewhere in Visual Studio which I can open and see these errors?

The windows that are automatically open during debug mode is Locals, and Call Stack. And they are completely empty.

Comment: I remember the problem I had with XNA, My code tried to access a negative index of an array. Yet NOTHING popped up in the debugger. I had to type WriteLine statements everywhere to find the error. XNA simply showed a red x. What a joke.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try breaking on all exceptions - [break on CLR exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  (Control/Alt + E to bring up the dialog, then check the Common Language Runtime Exceptions checkbox).

As you're debugging it should stop where the error occurs.

If you can't find anything that way, you might be able to see something by catching the overall AppDomain exception, or Threading exception - details [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much that did it! It gave me a few errors that I fixed and now everything works.

Comment: Wow this is some weird stuff. One thing my code had been doing is calling a method of a class through a null reference and updating some variables in it using the parameters passed through the method. That wasn't caught till I turned on your suggestion and it threw a NullReferenceException, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". It's weird that it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The red x in windows forms designer comes from an error in your paint code.
To debug this:

- open your solution in another visual studio instance
- Menu Debug > Attach to Process...
- select devenv.exe

then your first visual studio instance will be debuged and you can set breakpoints in your paint code.